# WPF Application have Win2000 style, but I'm using Win XP

Tags: wpf, windows, controls

Why does my application have the Windows 2000 style? I have the normal Windows XP - Style but the buttons and all the other controlls look like in Windows 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, WPF will use your system's current theme, i.e., if you are on Windows 7, then the Aero theme will be the default. The same will occur with Vista and XP themes. When WPF is unable to detect your theme, WPF will fall-back to the default "Classic" theme.

If you are seeing the Classic win2k theme, then a likely cause is you have modified your system's theme with something like the Zune theme or some other custom theme.

Comment: Yes, i installed the zune theme.